# Nodejs - retrieve value from nested and non-nested json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am passing `json` and a `key` to below function to retrieve its `value`. The key can be like abc.cde.def nad it can also be like fgh only.

If the keys contain `.` then it is a nested `json` and values has to be retrieved accordingly which is happening correctly but if it is a plain `json` having no nest then it is not working. Printing the length of keysData (in case the `key` is like fgh) it prints 3 where it should print 1.

```
function getValueFromJson(jsonInput,keyInput) {
    if(keyInput.includes('.')){
        var keysData = keyInput.split('.');
    }
    else {
        keysData = keyInput.toString()
    }
    var jsonHierarchy = jsonInput;
    if(parseInt(keysData.length) === parseInt('1')){        
        console.log(jsonHierarchy)
        console.log(keysData )
        console.log(jsonHierarchy[keysData ])
        jsonHierarchy = jsonHierarchy[keysData ];
    }   
    return jsonHierarchy;
};
```

Can anyone please help how can I handle this ?

Comment: You are getting that result because you are using the `.length` property on the key as a string data type. You need to make your `keysInput` into an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need to check for `if(keyInput.includes('.'))`

just do `keyInput.split('.')`

```
//for Ex.
'abc.defg'.split('.') // result ['abc', 'defg']
'abc'.split('.')  // result ['abc']
```

and also

```
if(parseInt(keysData.length) === parseInt('1'))

//can be used as
if(keysData.length === 1)
```

and your complete function should be

```
function getValueFromJson(jsonInput,keyInput) {
    var keysData = keyInput.split('.');

    var jsonHierarchy = jsonInput;
    keysData.forEach(function(d) {
        if(jsonHierarchy)
            jsonHierarchy = jsonHierarchy[d];
    }) 
    return jsonHierarchy;
};
```

```js
var jsonData = {
  'abc': {
    'def': {
      'gh': 'value1'
    },
    'xyz': 'value2'
  }
};

function getValueFromJson(jsonInput, keyInput) {
  var keysData = keyInput.split('.');

  var jsonHierarchy = jsonInput;
  keysData.forEach(function(d) {
    if (jsonHierarchy)
      jsonHierarchy = jsonHierarchy[d];
  })
  return jsonHierarchy;
};

function get() {
  var val = document.getElementById('key').value;
  if (val)
    console.log(getValueFromJson(jsonData, val));
};
```

```html
<input id="key" />
<button onclick="get()">Get Value</button>
```

Comment: This solved the problem but I am not able to retrieve values, it gives `undefined`

Comment: I am doing same like `console.log(jsonHierarchy[keysData])` but it gives undefined

Comment: `keysData` is an `Array` not `String` so you cant use it like that

Comment: Right, but retrieving as `console.log(jsonHierarchy[keysData[0]])` using index is also not helping. I tried like `s = keysData[0]
  console.log(jsonHierarchy[s])` but it also not helped

Comment: you are making it complicated.. i added one example snippet, check it out

Comment: It prints undefined only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121354/discussion-between-jag-and-abhinav).

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string to an array, then your length with show properly.

```
    var keysData = keyInput.split('.')
```

Comment: The entire `if/else` block is redundant, since it returns an array with the full string anyway if it doesn't find a match.

Comment: This solved the problem but I am not able to retrieve values, it gives 'undefined'.